# How can Netty handle socket created outside

Tags: sockets, netty

We have a socket server which was created and managed by another framework. We want let the Netty to handle the messages of the work socket which was created by that framework(this framework can get work socket, channel, selection key etc). How Netty can handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `NioSocketChannel` by passing a SocketChannel to the constructor. I think this should do what you want